# Programmatic approach to ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory makeView() method

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to create a simple class that implements the ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory interface basing on the project developed in "Sams Teach Yourself Android Application Development in 24 Hours". In the example the makeView() method inflates a layout in order to obtain a View. However, I wanted to do it programmatically and it didn't work.

The onCreate() method of the activity looks like this:

```
private TextSwitcher mQuestionText;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);

    mQuestionText = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.MyTextSwitcher);
    mQuestionText.setFactory(new MyTextSwitcherFactory());
    mQuestionText.setCurrentText("blablabla");
}
```

The proposed solution goes like this:

```
private class MyTextSwitcherFactory implements ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {
    public View makeView() {
        TextView textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(
        getApplicationContext()).inflate(
        R.layout.text_switcher_view,
        mQuestionText, false);
        return textView;
    }
}
```

The resource file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/title_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/game_question_size"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Testing String"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">
</TextView>
```

While I wanted to it like this:

```
private class MyImageSwitcherFactory implements ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {
    public View makeView() {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView.setLayoutParams(new TextSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        textView.setTextColor(R.color.title_color);
        textView.setTextSize(R.dimen.game_question_size);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setText("Test");
            return textView;
    }
}
```

I get the "blablabla" text displayed when I use the inflate method but not doing it programmatically. Could you point to an error in my code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong with the code I provided. This is wrong since it gives the ID of the resource as the function parameter instead of the value itself.

```
textView.setTextColor(R.color.title_color);
textView.setTextSize(R.dimen.game_question_size);
```

This is correct:

```
textView.setTextColor(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.title_color));
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getApplicationContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.game_question_size));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mQuestionText = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.MyTextSwitcher);
```

You're finding the view by the id `MyTextSwitcher`. Make sure you set that id if you're creating the view programmatically.

```
view.setId(R.id.MyTextSwitcher);
```

**Update:**

Whoops, didn't read your code carefully enough. You're right, since you're inflating from the XML, your ID should be set properly already. What you probably are missing is actually adding the view to the view hierarchy. You need to find a parent [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) (e.g. a `LinearLayout` or a 'RelativeLayout`, etc.) under which you want to put`MyTextSwitcher`, let's call it`root` and add it with something like:

```
root.addView(view);
```

Comment: That didn't help. The `mQuestionText` member gets initialized properly with the `R.id.MyTextSwitcher` ID and, if I understand correctly, gets provided with two TextViews by the factory. I don't get it why I should then set the ID of the provided TextViews in the `makeView()` method to the same ID the TextSwitcher has.

I looked into the debugger and the TextView with 'blablabla' is a child View of the TextSwitcher so the initialization seems to be working fine (even without the `setID()` call). However, it is still not displayed.

Comment: Updated with a bit more that you have to do.